# My file isn't loading from a web server, but I rename it and it's ok. Why does that happen?

Tags: css, apache

Occasionally on my websites, I notice an external file won't be loaded. If I rename it and point to the new name it works fine. The old name refuses to work ever again.

Usually this happens with images, but today it happened to a css file. It happens spontaneously and unpredictably. When it happens to images they won't load by themselves in a browser window either. The css will load by itself, but won't be loaded by the page linking to it.

Here are 2 pages which are exactly the same, except they link to 2 differently named css files. The css files are identical, except for their names.

working - http://internetfind.com.au/test2.html

not-working - http://internetfind.com.au/test1.html

The web server is Apache.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

i see on test1 the css file is not loaded as text/css but text/html. I also notice that you are running 2 different domains both running Apache. any chance you have 2 different .htaccess files? I am just speculating here as I dont have all the information but my guess would be the root directory running the test1 domain has a htaccess file where the MIME type are not defined right.

here is a link to a sample .htaccess file that comes with the html5 boilerplate distro. https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess

Another error is that Mordernizr is not defined which probably means that you have not linked the mordernizr library.

Answer (score 0):

test1.html is looking for this CSS

```
<link href="http://www.agedcarefind.com.au/styles/styles-church.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This CSS file is ending with

```
#prev{position:absolute;z-index:101;height:100%;…
```

Somwthing is wrong with the file, try to edit it and it should work fine

e.g:

```
#prev{position:absolute;z-index:101;height:100%;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Firefox console reports this:

> The stylesheet http://www.agedcarefind.com.au/styles/styles-church.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".

This suggests that your server isn't configured correctly and is serving the CSS with the wrong mimetype.

I can confirm the Firefox is requesting the file correctly, and it's being delivered - just not actioned.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, incorrect content-type for css files `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html`

Second - `Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined`

Content-type affects visualization of styles. May be you have some front-end server that changes content-type. Or your files are returned by server-side script - not enough details to answer clearly.

Based on the content of .css files I would say that you have some css compressor (removes white-spaces, new lines, reducing the size of .css file) running on server and may be it affects the content-type header.